# Can't uninstall any programs in safe mode

Tags: spam

Every time I try to open App manager(in Safe Mode) spams pop up, porn icons installs and so on. Simply, I  don't have time to reach the app manager. Help me please!
Smartphone: Getnord Cat

Comment: Are you sure that happens in [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info)? As user-apps cannot run there, that would mean some bad apps secretly rooted your device and converted themselves into system apps. The only way out in such a case is flashing a clean ROM.

Comment: yes,in safe mode.

Comment: Going to try factory reset

Comment: You can try that, but I doubt it will help. System apps are left untouched by a factory reset, so if some malware made it there it will survive it.

Comment: Did reset,but some programs still there.Its not my phone,so I not really familiar with normal android set up.But dont think programs like Beauty video,Lulu, MBrowser is normal factory set up:) .Either I did reset somehow wrong or virus somewhere deeper.I will try to do some scans with antivirus tomorrow.

Comment: As I already wrote: that malware made itself a system app. Only thing that helps is flashing a clean ROM. And no, no virus – this is not Windows. And I don't believe that some "Anti-Virus" can do something here (ant-what should it work, if there's no virus?). But good luck if you want to try. IMHO everything but a clean flash is wasted time here.

Comment: If u a right,how to clean ROM?Change it physically?

Comment: I didn't write "to clean a ROM", but to "flash a clean ROM" (i.e. "re-install Android"), see [rom-flashing](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info) ;)

Answer (score -1):

first can you download any apps if so download Avast mobile antivirus and do a scan if not plug the phone into your pc and copy all your pics,videos,music ect onto the pc. then do a hard reset on the phone. sounds like you got a bad virus.

Comment: 1. there are no viruses for Android, 2. as to the description it rather sounds like a malware that managed to convert itself into a system app (or it wouldn't be able to act in safe-mode), 3. Anti-Virus apps are pretty much useless (causing more trouble than they're solving), and 4. concluded from 2, no cleanup or [hard-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info) (uh? didn't you mean [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)?) would help, a factory-reset neither.

Comment: @Izzy A bit of a brutal bombardment, man. True though. It also occurred to me the OP could use adb commands to find and purge the software itself. Not gonna write an answer on it, as I am not an adb expert.

Comment: @DanB As I wrote: trying to clean the current installation, if possible at all, won't be easy. No guarantees you succeed – as it's hard to tell where the malware hides what. Once it managed to convert itself into a system app, it has full access to the device. So IMHO not even ADB would help to *completely* get rid of it. The only way is wiping everything by flashing a clean ROM.

Comment: @Izzy Fair enough man. I have a feeling the malware maker may have included a Install survival script to live through this- SuperSu has one, so it certainly is possible - which would make this nothing short of a nightmare.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised. As for your edit of the question: The addition to the title is not true. I doubt that any user-apps show up – it's rather the one malware app that most likely converted itself into a system app.

Comment: @Izzy Hmmm true. Thanks for fixing that one. I have done some digging- this "Lulu" app OP mentions is bizzare. And has lawsuits against it.